# Paginate none index page in Hexo

Tags: node.js, ejs, hexo

In Hexo, how do I paginate a page that's not the *index*? I have a page called: *blog.md* under pages, and have created a new file called *blog.ejs* in my layouts folder.

In the blog.md front matter I added:

```
layout: blog
```

And added to blog.ejs:

```
<ul>
<% page.posts.each(function(article){ %>
  <li><a href="<%- url_for(article.path) %>"><img src="/images/<%= article.imgfront %>" alt="" /></a></li>
<% }) %>
</ul>

<hr>

<% if (page.prev){ %>
    <a class="prev" href="<%- url_for(page.prev_link) %>">&larr; Prev</a>
<% } %>

<% if (page.next){ %>
    <a class="next" href="<%- url_for(page.next_link) %>">Next &rarr;</a>
<% } %>
```

But then get this error when I go to /blog:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: /Users/devserver/Desktop/hexo/themes/nadymain/layout/page.ejs:4
    2| 
    3| <ul>
 >> 4| <% page.posts.each(function(article){ %>
    5|   <li><a href="<%- url_for(article.path) %>"><img src="/images/<%= article.imgfront %>" alt="" /></a></li>
    6| <% }) %>
    7| </ul>

Cannot read property 'each' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? I am new to Hexo, but not sure if you can paginate a custom page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. `page.posts` Object is only available on **Home (index)** page.

Check [Hexo doc - Home (index) variables](https://hexo.io/docs/variables.html#Page-Variables) for more information

Here is the variables available on custom pages : [Hexo doc - Article (page) variables](https://hexo.io/docs/variables.html#Page-Variables)